# SQL запрос на фильтрацию дат

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
2023-06-22 23:08
2023-06-22 16:42
2023-06-22 11:58
2023-06-21 22:40
2023-06-21 18:00
2023-06-21 14:00
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать запрос к таблице, чтобы из указанных дат, выводились только самые поздние по времени?

```
2023-06-22 23:08
2023-06-21 22:40
```

Comment: Например можно чтобы была агрегация по дню и взять максимум за день. Или оконная функция. Реализация зависит от того какая  СУБД и описания таблицы. Добавьте тег какая именно БД и добавьте в текст описание БД. Хорошо бы добавить запрос на создание таблицы и вид итоговой таблицы с заголовками.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае, если версия СУБД позволяет использовать оконные функции, то примерно так:

```
SELECT dt
FROM (
    SELECT dt
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(dt) ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Да ну, зачем так сложно?

Comment: @rotabor потому что там наверняка понадобится выводить не только саму дату, но и остальные данные строки. Если только дату-время, то, конечно, хватит `max(dt) ... group by date(dt)`

Comment: Да, вполне логично

Comment: да, нужны все данные по колонкам, спасибо


select datetime, date, amount, account_balance
from nametable

Comment: Оба варианта, от teran и rotabor, мне нравятся. Разница между ними будет, если есть несколько строк с одинаковым временем по одной дате. Тогда вариант от teran ( с row_number()) выдаст одну из них, а другой - все. Можно выбрать, какой более подходит.

Comment: А сколько тонкостей! И как изменение постановки задачи может потребовать дополнительных уточнений! Если просто нужно вывести одну метку времени, то выводится единственный результат и он верный. А вот если нужны другие поля, тогда понадобится другой критерий для выбора записи (записей) из набора с одинаковым первым критерием. @ValNik

Comment: Это точно! Но основу вы задали.

Comment: @ValNik подобного поведения можно достичь используя `dense_rank()` вместо `row_number()`, я правда не в курсе относительно поддержки в обсуждаемой СУБД

Comment: Да, при использовании ``dense_rank()`` поведение двух вариантов будет одинаковым. Автор вопроса должен решить, какой использовать, что более подходит. Я посмотрел postgresql, с 9.3 по 15.0 поддерживает dense_rank().

Answer (score 3):

Поле datetime в исходной таблице Table1. Ответ точно на поставленный вопрос:

```
SELECT to_char(MAX(datetime),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI') AS Latesttime
FROM Table1
GROUP BY datetime::date;
```

Результат:

latesttime

2023-06-22 23:08

2023-06-21 22:40

Ну а если нужно больше, то

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(datetime) as Latesttime
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY datetime::date
) AS LT ON datetime = Latesttime
```